# Mysqli Commands out of sync

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

"Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

On this code:

```
$check = $dbc->prepare("SELECT field FROM table WHERE field = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($check, "s", $value1);
mysqli_stmt_execute($check);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($check, $info);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($check);

if ( $info == $static_value ) {

    $update = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE table SET field = 'valued' WHERE(field1 = ? AND field2 = ?)LIMIT 1");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update, "ss", $value1, $value2);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($update);
```

The code looks correct, where I wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, I edited now adding more informations, the error i'm getting is: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `update` query look very wrong. Try the following below,

Your old `update`,

```
$update = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE table SET field = 'valued' WHERE(field1 = ? AND field2 = ?)LIMIT 1");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update, "ss", $value1, $value2);
mysqli_stmt_execute($update);
```

Your new `$update`,

```
$update = mysqli_prepare($dbc, "UPDATE `yourTableName` SET `field` = 'valued' WHERE field1 = ? AND field2 = ?");
```

> LIMIT can be used with UPDATE but with the row count only.

**Edit 1**

You seem to be mixing `OO` `MySQLi` with `procedural`, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756002/is-it-acceptable-to-use-a-mix-of-object-oriented-style-with-procedural-style-in) page.

**Edit 2**

You had quite a few issues with your code.

1. You were trying to access `$email` and `$key` when they were out of the scope of the `if` so I added the new variables.
2. You kept on (as said above) mixing your `OO` with `procedural`.
3. I added some debugging when trying to execute `$update`.

   ```
   <?php

   $email;
   $key;

   if (isset($_GET['email']) && preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/', $_GET['email'])) {
       $email = $_GET['email'];
   }
   if (isset($_GET['key']) && (strlen($_GET['key']) == 32)) //The Activation key will always be 32 since it is MD5 Hash
       {
       $key = $_GET['key'];
   }


   if (isset($email) && isset($key)) {
       $check_code = mysqli_prepare($dbc, "SELECT Activation FROM members WHERE Email = ?");
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($check_code, "s", $email);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($check_code);
       mysqli_stmt_bind_result($check_code, $activation);
       mysqli_stmt_fetch($check_code);

       if ($activation == $key) {

           // Update the database to set the "activation" field to null

           $update = mysqli_prepare($dbc, "UPDATE `members` SET `Activation` = 'Activated' WHERE `Email` = ? AND `Activation` = ?");
           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update, "ss", $email, $key);
           mysqli_stmt_execute($update);

           if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($update) ) {
               die("Error: " . mysqli_stmt_error($update));
           }   


           // Print a customized message:
           if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //if update query was successfull

               echo '<div class="success">Your account is now active. You may now <a href="login.php">Log in</a></div>';

           } else {
               echo '<div class="errormsgbox">Oops !Your account could not be activated. Please recheck the link or contact the system administrator.</div>';
               echo '<br/> ' . $dbc->error;

           }

           mysqli_close($dbc);

       } else {

           echo "Parameters wrong, wrong link?";

       }

   } else {
       echo '<div class="errormsgbox">Error Occured .</div>';
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: @BlackSys now try it.

Comment: I'm kinda confused, so what I have to do? Based on the page you linked me, isn't it the same behaviour of the two functions?  edit: same error as above. I really don't get it, the syntax looks correct

Comment: tried it, however, i always get the error of out of sync. the syntax looks correct however, I really don't get it

Comment: It does not print the line error, but the first part of code, the $check one, is being executed correctly, or it will not pass the IF structure. so it must be the update query returning this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86516/discussion-between-script47-and-blacksys).

Answer (score 0):

wooo for a start you're mixing procedural and OOP, secondly you haven't closed your connections which is another error :)

```
$check=$dcv->prepare('SELECT field FROM table where field=?');
$check->bind_param('s',$value1);
$check->execute();
$check->bind_result($info);
$check->fetch();
$check->close();
if($info==$static_value){
    $update=$dvc->prepare('UPDTATE table SET field='valued' WHERE field1=? AND field2=?');
    $update->bind_param('ss',$value1,$value2);
    $result=$update->execute();
    $update->close();
}
```