# Getting failed when everything right

Tags: php, mysqli, imap

I am  trying to fetch email contents and put it in a mysqli table deposit.
Basically its coinpayments Emails which is sent when there is a deposit to an address. As they dont have an api for deposit history,I tried to develop an email reader which would read the email and put the address,username and txid in deposits table. The email when exploded to arrays looks like this

```
 Array ( [0] => -----BEGIN [1] => PGP [2] => SIGNED [3] => MESSAGE-----Hash: 
 [4] => SHA256Hello [5] => an user [6] => deposit [7] => of [8] => 
 an amount [9] => LTCT [10] => has [11] => been [12] => received [13] => 
 and [14] => confirmed [15] => into [16] => your [17] => CoinPayments [18] 
 => Wallet. [19] => The [20] => deposit [21] => was [22] => received [23] => 
 on [24] => an address [25] => with [26] => 
 transaction [27] => ID [28] => 
 an txid.Thank [29] 
 => you [30] => for [31] => using [32] => CoinPayments.net!Support [33] => 
 is [34] => available [35] => at: [36] => https://www.coinpayments.net/help- 
 support-----BEGIN [37] => PGP [38] => SIGNATURE----- 
 END [39] => PGP [40] => SIGNATURE----- )
```

Now i try to fetch most recent email using imap, delete it and put variables in deposits table.

```
   <?php
   $hostname = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Inbox";
   $username = 'username';
   $password = 'password';

    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());

  $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');


  if($emails)
 {
$output = '';

rsort($emails);

  $email_number = $emails[0];
{


    $message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.1)); 
    if($message == '')
    {
        $message = (imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1));
        $str =  "$message";
        $explode = (explode(" ",$str));
        $check = $explode[20];
        if ($check =='deposit') {
            $address = $explode[24];
            $textsplit = "$explode[28]";
            $split = (explode(".",$textsplit));
            $txid = $split[0];
            $signature = $explode[38];
            $date = date("Y-m-d");
            require ('setup.php');
                $conn = new mysqli($localhost, $hostuser, $hostpass, $hostdb) or die("conn died");
                $query1 = "SELECT user FROM addresses WHERE address = '$address'";  //Get username so i put it with txid in deposits table
               $result = $conn->query($query1);
                if ($result) {

             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              $user = $row['user'];
             }
                $query = "INSERT INTO deposits(tx, date, user, signature) VALUES('$txid', '$date', '$user', '$signature')";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($result) {
        echo 'inserted';
        $dl = imap_delete($inbox, $email_number);
        if ($dl) {
            echo 'deleted';
        }
        else {
            die('cant insert');
        }
    }
    else {
        die('failed1');
    }
        }
       else
       {
           die('failed');
       }


    }
}       
}
}
```

But at last i get "failed1".
I dont think there is any error. Please help me if you can =)

Comment: It would be useful if you displayed some meaningful errors rather than just 'failed1' - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments

Comment: give me a statement then  i will tell u which error

Comment: `date` is a MySQL keyword, don't use MySQL keywords as table/column names, it's just annoying to deal with. Depending on what you want to do you should rename it to something like `createdAt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query here:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Replace it with:

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

Comment: It's more a case of style than errors - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756002/is-it-acceptable-to-use-a-mix-of-object-oriented-style-with-procedural-style-in

Comment: @natashakrishnan In that case, please share the exact error you are getting. Print the exact query before executing and try to run that query and check if it is inserting the data or not.